# brew untap message on every new terminal window

Tags: terminal, homebrew

Every time I open a new terminal message I get this message from brew:

```
Last login: Mon Jul 14 17:57:51 on ttys000
Error: No available formula for php55
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap josegonzalez/php
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the resolution to this problem in the GitHub Issues page.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1084

"In this commit Homebrew/homebrew@9f4f854#diff-b3d0ec0137fd940e51500d90ca0f2fdcR155 the tap formula path changed to /usr/local/Library/Taps/josegonzalez-php/php55.rb, but the correct formula path is /usr/local/Library/Taps/josegonzalez-php/Formula/php55.rb

this is a quickfix:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Library/Taps/josegonzalez-php
$ ln -s Formula/* .
```

after this issue being fixed, don't forget reomve all symbol links using:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Library/Taps/josegonzalez-php
$ git clean -f
```

" - yesmek

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pico ~/.bash_profile
```

and delete the error items

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. Above solutions cannot solve it at all, and I finally find where the problem is:

1. open your `.bash_profile` or `.zsh.rc`
2. see from first line, is the one line added by brew like :

   `export PATH = "($brew --prefix josegonzalez-php)"`
3. and delete it, then <kbd>ESC</kbd> -> `:wq!`

Now reopen terminal window and you should see no message.

Now you can run `brew untap josegonzalez/php` or `brew untap josegonzalez-php` in your terminal. Hope it works for you.